# Calculate a sequence occurence of 15 min between two datetime

Tags: r, datetime

I have a table of date times and wish to add a new data frame in the hours of 00:00 to 00:00 in a sequences of 15 min, for each row, e.g. 00:00, 00:15, ... 23:45 where I am trying to find the number of times a worker have been working in his schedule.

Note that the datetime format is `d-m-Y h:m`

I have (changed to my data)

```
worker           Start_shift        End_shift          difference        
Worker  130    30-05-2018 15:00   01-06-2018 08:15   41.25     
Worker  130    15-06-2018 15:00   16-06-2018 09:00   18.00     
Worker  130    22-03-2018 15:00   23-03-2018 08:15   17.25     
Worker  130    27-02-2018 15:00   28-02-2018 10:00   19.00     
Worker  130    30-05-2018 15:00   01-06-2018 08:15   41.25     
Worker  18    27-04-2018 15:00   29-04-2018 07:24   40.40     
Worker  11    29-03-2018 16:00   31-03-2018 07:24   39.40     
Worker  11    25-03-2018 16:00   27-03-2018 07:24   39.40
```

I wish to have a new dataframe this output. Where I can see how much they work in the different timestamps

This is just an **example of the desired output**, not the true output of the above dataset. The counts below could be wrong.

```
            00:00 | 00:15 | 00:30 | ... | 23:45 
worker 130     5      5       6       ..    4
worker 18      2      5       5       ..    3
worker 11      1      1       1       ..    1
```

I have tried to create a sequence of 15 mins with the seq() call.

`seq15 <- seq(lubridate::as_datetime(paste0(DATE_Start, " 00:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"),
lubridate::as_datetime(paste0(DATE_End, " 00:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"), by = "15 mins")`

However with the longer shifts I can't add the timestamps together

Any help would be appreciated

dput is below

```
structure(list(Start_shift = c("30-05-2018 15:00", "15-06-2018 15:00", 
"22-03-2018 15:00", "27-02-2018 15:00", "30-05-2018 15:00", "27-04-2018 15:00", 
"29-03-2018 16:00", "29-03-2018 16:00"), End_shift = c("01-06-2018 08:15", 
"16-06-2018 09:00", "23-03-2018 08:15", "28-02-2018 10:00", "01-06-2018 08:15", 
"29-04-2018 07:24", "31-03-2018 07:24", "31-03-2018 07:24"), 
    difference = structure(c(41.25, 18, 17.25, 19, 41.25, 40.4, 
    39.4, 39.4), class = "difftime", units = "mins"), worker = structure(c(30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 8L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Worker  11", 
    "Worker  12", "Worker  13", "Worker  14", "Worker  15", "Worker  16", 
    "Worker  17", "Worker  18", "Worker  19", "Worker  110", 
    "Worker  111", "Worker  112", "Worker  113", "Worker  114", 
    "Worker  115", "Worker  116", "Worker  117", "Worker  118", 
    "Worker  119", "Worker  120", "Worker  121", "Worker  122", 
    "Worker  123", "Worker  124", "Worker  125", "Worker  126", 
    "Worker  127", "Worker  128", "Worker  129", "Worker  130", 
    "Worker  131", "Worker  132", "Worker  133", "Worker  134", 
    "Worker  135", "Worker  136", "Worker  137", "Worker  138", 
    "Worker  139", "Worker  140"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(7052L, 
7053L, 7054L, 7055L, 7074L, 1767L, 21L, 58L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the data you posted as `dt`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


dt %>%
  mutate(Start_shift = dmy_hm(Start_shift),
         End_shift = dmy_hm(End_shift)) %>%           # update to datetime
  rowwise() %>%                                       # for each row
  mutate(date_vec = list(seq(Start_shift, 
                             End_shift, 
                             by = "15 mins"))) %>%    # create a vector of 15 min distance date-times
  ungroup() %>%                                       # forget the grouping
  unnest() %>%                                        # unnest vector of date-times
  mutate(time = substr(date_vec, 12,16)) %>%          # keep only hr-mins
  count(worker, time) %>%                             # count combinations
  spread(time, n)                                     # reshape
```

And an alternative, a bit more compact, solution that uses `map` to replace `rowwise`, while generating the date-time vectors and keeping hr-mins at the same time:

```
dt %>%
  mutate(Start_shift = dmy_hm(Start_shift),
         End_shift = dmy_hm(End_shift),      
         time = map2(Start_shift, End_shift, ~substr(seq(.x, .y, by = "15 mins"), 12, 16))) %>%
  unnest(time) %>%
  count(worker, time) %>%                          
  spread(time, n)
```

Comment: I am getting the error: `Error in seq.POSIXt(start, end, by = "15 mins") : 
  'from' must be of length 1`. And what would be the best way to post some of my data? Download from gdrive or?

Would this work if I have multiple rows with the same worker. See the updated table

Comment: Use `dput(d)`, where `d` is a small sample of your dataset. A good example is `df = mtcars[1:3,];
dput(df)` and then copy and paste what `dput` returns on your console under your question.

Comment: I have changed it to the date I have. I have also anonymised the names. Hope it makes sense now :)

Comment: Done, remember that I have anonymised the names, but I guess it shouldn't matter?

Comment: Are you sure that the desired dataset is correct? For example, why worker 18 has `1` for `00:15`?

Comment: Sorry I saw wrong in the desired dataset, it should be more, since the work is 40 hours here. But basically it should be a sum of all the work hours they have made in a 15 min interval

Comment: Hmm thats wierd I took it from the dataset. But Have changed to not be in the same date

Comment: We can easily add a process to remove duplicates. But, first, you need to check that the process runs successfully

Comment: Will check it, give me a moment :)

Comment: Use ONLY the example data you posted first. Not your full dataset, as it will be easier to spot any bugs. If that works OK then you'll use full data.

Comment: It seems to work flawless on both the example data and the full dataset. Thank you it was exactly what I looked for :)

Comment: If you ever come to Denmark, Copenhagen I'll buy you  a beer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190952/discussion-between-kazyka-and-antoniosk).